# nodejs - GraphicMagick - Add images in a frame to create another image

Tags: node.js, graphicsmagick, node-imagemagick

I have a sample image frame(see below) saved in the server and a function that will take an array of image URLs, crop the images into a circular shape to match the height /width of a cat image in the frame (60px x 60px) and replace cats from the left depending on the number of images and finally save the image back
I need to know how to do this using graphicMagick in node.js.

Just to be more clear

- I have an image frame.png
- I have an array of two URLs ['www.someurl.com/image1.jpg', 'www.someurl.com/image2.jpg]
- for each URL in the array

  - Download image i from URL into a temp location
  - Crop the image i into a circular shape of radius 60.
  - Put it on top of frame.png at some position (xi,yi)
- Save the new composite image
- upload it back

[image: Sample frame]

Comment: Did you try anything ? Where is the sample code ? Failed attempts at the problem ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here I am posting my solution what I did to circularize image and then compose them on a frame image (png).
The only downside to this solution is that there are multiple writes to the file and I couldn't do it in a single write.

I hope this helps someone in the future,

```
const gm = require('gm').subClass({ imageMagick: true })

export async function convertToCircularImage(imagePath: string, resultPath: string) {
  const radius = 180

  return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
    gm(imagePath)
      .autoOrient()
      .gravity('Center')
      .resize(radius, radius, '^')
      .extent(radius, radius)
      .noProfile()
      .setFormat('png')
      .out('(')
      .rawSize(radius, radius)
      .out('xc:Black')
      .fill('White')
      .drawCircle(radius / 2, radius / 2, radius / 2, 1)
      .out('-alpha', 'Copy')
      .out(')')
      .compose('CopyOpacity')
      .out('-composite')
      .trim()
      .write(resultPath, (err: Error) => {
        if (err) {
          console.error('Failed to crop image.', err)
          reject(err)
        } else {
          console.log(`Cropped image at ${imagePath} and saved it at ${resultPath}`)
          resolve(resultPath)
        }
      })
  })
}

export async function composite(
  frameImagePath: string,
  circularImagesPaths: string[],
  resultImagePath: string,
  points: string[],
) {

  let frameImage = frameImagePath
  let index = 0
  for (const circularImagePath of circularImagesPaths) {
    const point = points[index]
    try {
      // this method return the resultImagePath which is then used as a frame for next composition
      frameImage = await composeImage(frameImage, circularImagePath, point, resultImagePath)
    } catch (e) {
      console.log('Composite: some error', e)
    }
    index = index + 1
  }
}

async function composeImage(
  frameImage: string,
  circularImage: string,
  point: string,
  resultPath: string,
): Promise<string | any> {
  console.log('Composing circular image to frame...', frameImage, circularImage)
  return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
    gm(frameImage)
      .composite(circularImage)
      .in('-compose', 'Dst_Over') // to only overlap on transparent parts
      .geometry(point)
      .in()
      .write(resultPath, function (err: any) {
        if (err) {
          console.error('Composing failed', err)
          reject(err)
        } else {
          console.log('Composing complete')
          resolve(resultPath)
        }
      })
  })
}
```

Comment: Hi sumit,

I need some help regarding setting the image on the iframe using the node js. Can you please help me?

I have two images first one is of a coffee Mug and another one is of a girl. I can set the image of the girl on the coffee mug can you please me?